# How would I use a specific webpart from the SP Starter Kit (SPFx) Currently getting error TS2307

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, spfx, react-typescript

I am currently trying to use the [People Directory Webpart](https://github.com/pnp/sp-starter-kit/blob/master/documentation/components/wp-people-directory.md) from SP Starter Kit. I have my baseline NPM setup done to the point where I can run `gulp serve` and be shown the "Hello World" webpart, but when I attempt to `gulp serve` with the "People Directory" Webpart pasted into my webpart folder next to my "Hello World" I am met with the following error:

```
Error - typescript - src\webparts\peopleDirectory\components\PeopleDirectory\PeopleDirectory.tsx(11,29): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@pnp/spfx-controls-react/lib/WebPartTitle'.
```

The lines referred to above:

11: `import { WebPartTitle } from "@pnp/spfx-controls-react/lib/WebPartTitle";`

24-35:

```
export class PeopleDirectory extends React.Component<IPeopleDirectoryProps, IPeopleDirectoryState> {
  constructor(props: IPeopleDirectoryProps) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      errorMessage: null,
      selectedIndex: 'A',
      searchQuery: '',
      people: []
    };
  }
```

I am fully aware that this problem is probably only happening to me because of my total lack of experience because it feels like something that is relatively easy to fix. But in the huge file structure that comes with all of this I am getting very lost and confused, my own efforts over the last few days to figure this out have only made me more confused. Just point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Some other basic info:

Gulp version: 4.0.2

Yo version: 3.1.1

@microsoft/generator-sharepoint version: 1.11.0

Typescript version: 4.5.4

Answer (score 0):

Go to package.json file:
you should have this line in that file:

```
"@pnp/spfx-controls-react": "^1.15.0",
```

if yes, try to run command in terminal npm i - this will install all dependencies.
if not, check source package.json https://github.com/pnp/sp-starter-kit/blob/master/source/react-people-directory/package.json and copy all dependencies and then run npm i (in your project folder).